# Search a node in a binary tree in C

Tags: c, search, binary-tree

I have a binary tree (not a binary search tree, BST) like this

```C
// node in a tree
typedef struct
{
    int id;         // node index in a tree
    int value;      // data on node
    struct Node* l; // left child
    struct Node* r; // right child
} Node;

// a tree with only its root node
typedef struct
{
    Node* root;
} BiTree;
```

I want to **find a node by its `id` (for a given index `idToBeFound`) and return the pointer of the found node**.
My search function `findNode` works properly for `case 1` below but not for `case 2` (seems to go into a endless loop):

Examples (numbers shown here are the indices of nodes and `value`=`id` for simplicity): if looking for node with id = 2, the output should be the pointer of node 2.

`case 1`:

```
     1
    / \
   2
  / \
 3
/ \
```

`case 2`:

```
 1
/ \
   2
  / \
     3
    / \
```

```C
// finds a node in a tree and returns its pointer
Node* findNode(Node *node, int idToBeFound)
{
    printf("traversing node %.2d with value = %d\n", node->id, node->value);

    if (node == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to find!");
        return NULL;
    }

    if (idToBeFound == node->id)
    {
        printf("returning node %d\n", node->id);
        return node;
    }

    Node* node1 = findNode(node->l, idToBeFound);
    if(node1 != NULL)
    {
        printf("returning the left child of node %d\n", node->id);
        return node1;
    }

    Node* node2 = findNode(node->r, idToBeFound);
    if(node2 != NULL)
    {
        printf("returning the right child of node %d\n", node->id);
        return node2;
    }
}
```

```C
int main(void)
{
    BiTree tree;
    initTree(&tree);

    //tree.root = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    //createTreePreOderRecur(tree.root);        // create a tree recursively
    
    printf("Demo: find a node via its id in a tree:\n");
    int IdToBeFound = 2;
    printf("Id of node to be found = %d\n", IdToBeFound);

    Node* nodeFound = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    nodeFound = findNode(tree.root, IdToBeFound);

    printf("the found node is: id = %d, value = %d\n", nodeFound->id, nodeFound->value);

    //destoryTreeRecur(tree.root);

    return 0;
}
```

Any problem in function `findNode`? (other codes work well and are neglected here). Thanks.

Comment: What happens if both `node1` and `node2` are `NULL`? It looks like the function `findNode()` is missing a `return NULL` at the end. Your compiler should have warned you about it. If not, turn on compiler warnings and fix all of them.

Comment: `Node* nodeFound = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    nodeFound = findNode(tree.root, IdToBeFound);` <<-- you are leaking memory here

Comment: @wildplasser: I free `nodeFound` and the problem remains, so perhaps not due to memory leaking.

Comment: @G. Sliepen: I added a line of code `return NULL;` behind `if(node2 != NULL){...}` for the case you pointed out, not worked.

Comment: Could it be that the function creating the tree has a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the right code now, which runs correctly:

```C
Node* findNode(Node *node, int value)
{
    printf("traversing node %d with value = %d\n", node->id, node->value);

    Node *temp = NULL;

    // case 1:
    if (node->id == value)
    {
        return node;
    }

    // case 2: if the root node is not the right one, traverse its left child
    if (node->l != NULL)
    {
        printf("traversing the left child of node %d\n", node->id);
        temp = findNode(node->l, value);
        if (temp != NULL) return temp;
    }

    // case 3: if the left node is not the right one, traverse its right child
    if (node->r != NULL)
    {
        printf("traversing the right child of node %d\n", node->id);
        temp = findNode(node->r, value);
        if (temp != NULL) return temp;
    }

    // case 4: if the root node and its children are not the right one, return NULL
    return temp;
}

int main(void)
{
    BiTree tree;
    ...

    int IdToBeFound = 2;    
    printf("Demo: find a node via its id in a tree:\n");
    printf("The id of node to find is %d\n", IdToBeFound);

    Node* nodeFound = findNode(tree.root, IdToBeFound);
    
    /* 
    Check the result by evaluating the pointer nodeFound
    1: nodeFound = NULL means failure to find (e.g., the node is not in the tree), 
    2: nodeFound != NULL means success.
    */
    if(nodeFound != NULL) 
    {
        printf("the found node is: id = %d, value = %d\n", nodeFound->id, nodeFound->value);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("failed to find node %d in the tree!\n", IdToBeFound);
        free(nodeFound);
    }

    ...

    return 0;
}
```